# sql while loop by checking condition contains a word in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a while loop and need to check the loop condition from a string. The string is a set of words separated by commas Eg:'abc, bcd, gfd'.

I want to check whether a specific word is contains or not inside the string. If a word is present in the string then i want to enter into the loop and execute it. I try with CHARINDEX but it not gives full text search.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 'abc, bcd, hbg'

while(contains(@string ,'abc'))

BEGIN

    ///

END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code attempt is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server... Code is for just show an example

Comment: `while(@string like '%abc%')` ??

Comment: @huMpty duMpty i want exact word search.. when use 'like' even the word '%abcd%' will also consider. But that is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL server 2016 and above:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(200) = 'abc,bcd,hbg'
DECLARE @string1 varchar(200) = 'abc'

select value from string_split(@string,',')
where value=@string1;
```

In SQL server lower version you need to create function to get the results

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do like this?

```
DECLARE @list varchar(8000)
DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @value varchar(8000)

SET @list = 'abc, bcd, hbg,abc,'

set @pos = 0
set @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @list, @pos+1) > 0
BEGIN
        set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @list, @pos+1) - @pos
        set @value = SUBSTRING(@list, @pos, @len)            

        IF(@value = 'abc')
         BEGIN
            PRINT @value
            --DO YOUR MAGIC HERE        
         END
        set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @list, @pos+@len) +1
END
```

Comment: which sql version did you use?

Comment: sql server 2016